# A reference within a method that is identical to one of its parameters reference refers to the parameter correct?

Tags: lambda, scope

[Towards the end of this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#accessing-local-variables) in a oracle tutorial of lambda expressions it seems as if it is saying that `x` is referring to a member in the enclosing class of the method, but since the method has a parameter reference identical to `x` I think it refers to the local parameter and not a member of the enclosing class.

> For example, the lambda expression directly accesses the parameter x of the method methodInFirstLevel. To access variables in the enclosing class, use the keyword this. In this example, this.x refers to the member variable FirstLevel.x.

But then the tutorial seems to immediately contradict itself:

> However, like local and anonymous classes, a lambda expression can only access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or effectively final. For example, suppose that you add the following assignment statement immediately after the methodInFirstLevel definition statement:

```
void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
    x = 99;
    // ...
}
```

> Because of this assignment statement, the variable FirstLevel.x is not effectively final anymore.

What? The assignment in that example method is `x =` not `this.x =` so how does that assignment affect `FirstLevel.x` at all?

Comment: `x` parameter is like is a local variable, whose scope is the method. What’s your question exactly?

Comment: I just edited it. Does this help clarify my question? I'm confused as to how the assignment within the quoted method affects `FirstLevel.x` instead of the parameter `x` I don't think the tutorial is correct in saying this

Comment: My problem is with what member the assignment is affecting. I understand what they are saying about being effectively final

Comment: If you could Bohemian, please let me know if you think Oracle made a mistake in saying this. Me and another person here thinks it's a typo, but I just want to be dead sure. Your confirmation would solidify that for me

Comment: I believe the tutorial is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gathered, the tutorial was saying that the `x = 99` in the example lambda function was **not** accessing the class member variable. It was attempting to modify the function parameter, which must be final, therefore, it was an invalid operation. The `x = 99` would have generated an error.

The tutorial later said that it affected the member variable, `FirstLevel.x`. This was incorrect, as `x = 99` can only reference the function parameter. On the other hand, `this.x` would have referenced `FirstLevel.x`.

Comment: but then why does it say "Because of this assignment statement, the variable FirstLevel.x is not effectively final anymore." immediately after the example method? `FirstLevel.x` is the class member variable

Comment: I see what you mean now. As far as I know, the tutorial was incorrect.

Comment: I don't think the example method affects `FirstLevel.x` at all. I think it only causes the parameter `x` to not become final anymore. All I can surmise is that the notation `FirstLevel.x` may be some unique way of referring to the parameter of the method possibly?

Comment: I agree, the `x = 99` was not referencing `FirstLevel.x`. I don't know if they were trying to refer to the function parameter by saying `FirstLevel.x`, but I highly doubt they were, as that would be incredibly confusing.

Comment: Do you think it was a typo? That's what I think

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I will modify my answer to include this.

Comment: I believe the tutorial is incorrect, as you say.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just seeing the edit in your answer. Accepted

Answer (score 0):

As a general thing what is passed to a function is a reference.
Within the function a local variable is then assigned this reference.  It does not generally cause any change to the variable outside the function unless you cause this with some form of global variable.
The coincidence of names does not cause any issue because they point to different memory locations.

Comment: Then why does the tutorial say the assignment in the example method causes the enclosing class variable to not be effectively final anymore? I understand that the parameter of the method and the enclosing class member are two different memory locations, I don't understand how the assignment within this example method would affect the enclosing class member `FirstLevel.x`